# How to change IP of system problematically in a Windows service or console app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, ip, ip-address

I'm writing a C# application and want to change the IP address of my system.

I found this command

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.191 255.255.255
```

But how can I do this in code?

Comment: i wana do it with c# help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, using `System.Diagnotics.Process` class.

```
string result;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "interface ip add address name=\"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.1.191 255.255.255";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
try
{
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit(30000);
   result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   result = ex.Message;
}

// check "result" variable for your results.
```

Comment: yeap you are write but getting The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).\n\r\n

Comment: dude its worked by some of my rnd on it ;) thanks again